# Three Digit Numbers Above $560$ Formed From $3,4,5,6,7$

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a straight forward way of calculating the number of three digit numbers greater than 560 that can be formed from the numbers $3,4,5,6$, and $7$. I found it to be $30$ but I did it in a round about way. Is there a better method? Repeated digits are not allowed.

Comment: The title doesn't match the body of the question. Please clarify whether "above $560$" is part of the question.

Comment: What you mean by *the number of three digit numbers that can be formed from the numbers 3,4,5,6, and 7* ? Formed in what way?

Comment: Just go case by case, working off the first digit.  If it is $6,7$ then any pair that follows is good.  If it is $5$ then the second must be $6,7$ but the third can be anything.

Answer (score 3):

I think going through the cases is straightforward. That is,

To have a three digit number greater than $560$ we need the first two digits to be at least $56$.

If the number starts with $56$ then there are 3 choices for the final digit.
If the number starts with $57$ then there are 3 choices for the final digit.
If the number starts with $6$ then there are $4\times 3$ choices for the last two digits.
If the number starts with $7$ then there are $4\times 3$ choices for the last two digits.

This list of cases are all the possible cases, so the total number is $30$ as you say.

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, the median of all three-digit numbers with non-repeated digits $3$ to $7$ is $555$. Since there are no such numbers between $555$ and $560$, you want exactly half of them. There's a total of $5\cdot4\cdot3$ of them, and half of that is $30$.

Answer (score 0):

pick a number for the first must be a $(5, 6 ,7)$ then pick a second number, if $5$ is first our choices are $(6,7)$ this has probability $1/3$. if $6$ or $7$ is chosen then any number can come next so $3×(2/3)×4 ×3+3×(1÷3)×2×3= total$

Comment: Three digits, not five.

Comment: The indices in the binomial coefficient are swapped; but $\binom53$ is also wrong, since it doesn't take the order of the digits into account.

Comment: i'm just going to assume he wants under 560 because I don't want to do the rest of the calculation to finish the answer, and i've answered his question